# NSTimer doesn't call his selector

Tags: ios, objective-c, nstimer

In my app I need to setup a timer and at the end of this timer I will do some action.
I created a timer with following code:

```
@interface ViewController ()

@property(nonatomic)NSTimer *timer;

@end
```

Then I made some check and if the audio frequency I get is < 18000 I should start the timer and wait 10 seconds to show an alert.
I made this code so:

```
- (void)frequencyChangedWithValue:(float)newFrequency {
    frequencyRecived = newFrequency;
    watermarkReceived = YES;

    if (frequencyRecived > 18000) {

        [self.timer invalidate];
        self.timer = nil;

        if (frequencyRecived >= 18000 && frequencyRecived <= 18110 && !water1) {
            [self setTextInLabel:@"1"];
            water2 = water3 = water4 = NO;
            water1 = YES;
        }
        if (frequencyRecived >= 18115 && frequencyRecived <= 18250 && !water2) {
            [self setTextInLabel:@"2"];
            water1 = water3 = water4 = NO;
            water2 = YES;
        }
        if (frequencyRecived >= 18255 && frequencyRecived <= 18440 && !water3) {
            setTextInLabel:@"3"];
            water1 = water2 = water4 = NO;
            water3 = YES;
        }
        if (frequencyRecived >= 18450 && !water4) {
            [self setTextInLabel:@"4"];
            water1 = water2 = water3 = NO;
            water4 = YES;
        }
    } else {
        if (self.timer == nil) {
            self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10.0 target:self selector:@selector(noPosition) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
        }
        water1 = water2 = water3 = water4 = NO;
    }
}

- (void)noPosition {
    [self.timer invalidate];
    self.timer = nil;
    [self setTextInLabel:@"Nessuna postazione"];
}
```

But when I receive an audio signal with a frequency < 18000, I initialize the NSTimer but it doesn't call the selector method, what's wrong in my code?

Comment: ve you put checkpoint whether its coming inside else if so when?? when it becoming (timer==nill)??

Comment: Your code looks OK to me.  How are you testing it?

Comment: As usual: I get 4 different audio signal with different frequency, I execute the app directly on the iPhone, but when the audio signal are not enabled it never calls the selector method

Comment: There's definitely nothing wrong with the timer part. Need to check the If conditions.

Comment: Are you checking this using breakpoints (whether it is coming to the noPosition selector) or just seeing the output of the label text getting changed in the device?

Comment: I put a breakpoint just in the selector to see if the timer calls it, but it doesn't execute this code section. The if conditions are correct indeed when the frequency reach a threshold it change the label in the UI

Comment: Are you sure your frequencyChangedWithValue method isn't being called again after the timer is created?  As written, if it gets called with a frequency > 18000 it will cancel the timer before it gets invoked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method signature used in `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:` must have an argument for the `NSTimer` as it passes the timer to the method. Everything should work fine if you change

```
- (void)noPosition
```

to

```
- (void)noPosition:(NSTimer*)aTimer
```

and call it like

```
self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10.0 target:self selector:@selector(noPosition:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

Comment: And that would stop it being called?

Comment: It doesn't work, I just tried it now and I'm getting the same problem: the NSTimer doesn't call the selector

Comment: @Volker you are right - as per documentation, but without the parameter also it seems to work.